# Keep information in div always display with specific number of lines

Tags: html, css, height, line, paragraph

I have a question about how can I keep the information inside a div always displays within a specific number of lines.

As stated as the structure inside the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2avzp0z/), I have 3 kinds of information to be displayed within a div. Sometime each of them will be short as one line only, but sometimes they may be long name displayed in multiple lines. And for the "`<p class="promotion-content">`" which may appear occasionally.

So what I want is those information in the div will always display within 3 lines. If there is information inside the "promotion-content", only the promotion content will be shown, it will still be 3 lines height even its information has less that 3 lines.

So when I do not contain any promotion, only brand name and product name will be shown and they are limited as 3 lines height.  But if both names are short that only have 2 lines, I will still have a empty 3rd. Can I do it with HTML and CSS other than adding a 
 by myself for each related product?

I am confused about the way to do all these and I have tried with height limitation but seems it doesn't work. I am wondering if they can be done by HTML and CSS tricks?? Can someone please give me some direction on it? Thanks!!!

Comment: you can use `ul.a {list-style-type: circle;}
ul.b {list-style-type: square;}
ol.c {list-style-type: upper-roman;}
ol.d {list-style-type: lower-alpha;}`

Comment: @lalitbhakuni hi thank you for your reply. But I am not saying that I want to state the line numbers. But I want to keep the information display with 3 lines, if information is in small amount, it will still display with space for 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-height to the div

In HTML

```
    <div class="information">
      <p class="promotion-content">
      Buy 1 Get 1 Free
      </p>
      <p class="brand-name">
      ABC Brand
      </p>
      <p class="product-name">
      Product Name
      </p>
    </div>
```

In CSS

```
    .information {
      min-height:120px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

you can refer this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2avzp0z/1/)

Comment: Min-height may be working for some cases... but if I may adjust the text size later on, is there any ways for the min-height to change with respect to the change of font size??

Comment: You can use css flex property for this. Refer this sample flex example https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard. Let me know if it works.